# Excel: a formula which will identify partial text in one cell that exists in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 150,000 rows in a table.  One of the columns includes email addresses included on an invoice and another column has email addresses included on the quote.  When there us just one email address in each column, an IF statement is fine.
However, the invoice column often contains more than one email address, whereas the Q column only contains one.  I want to identify if any of the email addresses in the invoice cell matches the email address in the q cell

Comment: I don't know the exact formula you need, but the SEARCH() macro is probably what you want. Something like SEARCH(O, Q) != #VALUE! should do it.

Comment: ^^^ If the above formula doesn't do what you want, then please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1763080/edit) to provide sample data and the expected outcome